# Can't run parallel jobs with SLURM on Ubuntu 18.04 on same machine

Tags: slurm

Seems i can't run parallel jobs on the same node. 
I've set up SLURM on a single machine (Ubuntu 18.04 CPUs=8 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=1 CoresPerSocket=4 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=15976) to use with Kaldi.

To test if i can execute jobs in parallel i've used a short python snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# demo.py:
# usage: python demo.py [job-number]

import sys
import socket
from time import sleep


def work(jobnum):
  print("Starting job {} on {}.".format(jobnum, socket.gethostname()))
  sleep(5)
  print("Finished job {}...\n".format(jobnum))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  jobnum = sys.argv[1]
  work(jobnum)
```

And then basically i tried to execute three jobs in parallel as:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=3
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1

# Execute jobs in parallel
srun -c 1 --exclusive python demo.py 0 &
srun -c 1 --exclusive python demo.py 1 &
srun -c 1 --exclusive python demo.py 2 &
wait
```

I've tried pretty much all sort of things with #SBATCH arguments to no avail. They are always executed sequentially. 
Using squeue -o "%all" i found that basically the first job has 8 cpus while the second and third 1 cpus and thus are queued as the first job is taking all resources. 
So it must be something related to the installation or configuration. 
Here is my configuration file:

```
# slurm.conf file generated by configurator.html.
# Put this file on all nodes of your cluster.
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
ControlMachine=sam-red
#ControlAddr=
#BackupController=
#BackupAddr=
#
AuthType=auth/munge
#CheckpointType=checkpoint/none
CryptoType=crypto/munge
#DisableRootJobs=NO
#EnforcePartLimits=NO
#Epilog=
#EpilogSlurmctld=
#FirstJobId=1
#MaxJobId=999999
#GresTypes=
#GroupUpdateForce=0
#GroupUpdateTime=600
#JobCheckpointDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/checkpoint
#JobCredentialPrivateKey=
#JobCredentialPublicCertificate=
#JobFileAppend=0
#JobRequeue=1
#JobSubmitPlugins=1
#KillOnBadExit=0
#LaunchType=launch/slurm
#Licenses=foo*4,bar
#MailProg=/usr/bin/mail
#MaxJobCount=5000
#MaxStepCount=40000
#MaxTasksPerNode=128
MpiDefault=none
#MpiParams=ports=#-#
#PluginDir=
#PlugStackConfig=
#PrivateData=jobs
ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid
#Prolog=
#PrologFlags=
#PrologSlurmctld=
#PropagatePrioProcess=0
#PropagateResourceLimits=
#PropagateResourceLimitsExcept=
#RebootProgram=
ReturnToService=1
#SallocDefaultCommand=
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmd
SlurmUser=sam
#SlurmdUser=root
#SrunEpilog=
#SrunProlog=
StateSaveLocation=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmctld
SwitchType=switch/none
#TaskEpilog=
TaskPlugin=task/none
#TaskPluginParam=
#TaskProlog=
#TopologyPlugin=topology/tree
#TmpFS=/tmp
#TrackWCKey=no
#TreeWidth=
#UnkillableStepProgram=
#UsePAM=0
#
#
# TIMERS
#BatchStartTimeout=10
#CompleteWait=0
#EpilogMsgTime=2000
#GetEnvTimeout=2
#HealthCheckInterval=0
#HealthCheckProgram=
InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
#MessageTimeout=10
#ResvOverRun=0
MinJobAge=300
#OverTimeLimit=0
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=300
#UnkillableStepTimeout=60
#VSizeFactor=0
Waittime=0
#
#
# SCHEDULING
#DefMemPerCPU=0
FastSchedule=1
#MaxMemPerCPU=0
#SchedulerRootFilter=1
#SchedulerTimeSlice=30
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SchedulerPort=7321
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
#
#
# JOB PRIORITY
#PriorityFlags=
#PriorityType=priority/basic
#PriorityDecayHalfLife=
#PriorityCalcPeriod=
#PriorityFavorSmall=
#PriorityMaxAge=
#PriorityUsageResetPeriod=
#PriorityWeightAge=
#PriorityWeightFairshare=
#PriorityWeightJobSize=
#PriorityWeightPartition=
#PriorityWeightQOS=
#
#
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING
#AccountingStorageEnforce=0
#AccountingStorageHost=
#AccountingStorageLoc=
#AccountingStoragePass=
#AccountingStoragePort=
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
#AccountingStorageUser=
AccountingStoreJobComment=YES
ClusterName=cluster
#DebugFlags=
#JobCompHost=
#JobCompLoc=
#JobCompPass=
#JobCompPort=
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
#JobCompUser=
#JobContainerType=job_container/none
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=3
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log
#SlurmSchedLogFile=
#SlurmSchedLogLevel=
#
#
# POWER SAVE SUPPORT FOR IDLE NODES (optional)
#SuspendProgram=
#ResumeProgram=
#SuspendTimeout=
#ResumeTimeout=
#ResumeRate=
#SuspendExcNodes=
#SuspendExcParts=
#SuspendRate=
#SuspendTime=
#
#
# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=sam-red CPUs=8 RealMemory=14000 Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=4 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=shared Nodes=sam-red Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

I am pretty much a newbie regarding schedulers, maybe it could be a trivial issue for someone with more experience.

UPDATE:

submitting the job with:

```
#!/bin/bash

srun --nodes=1 --nodelist=sam-red --ntasks=1 --oversubscribe  python demo.py 0  &
srun --nodes=1 --nodelist=sam-red --ntasks=1 --oversubscribe  python demo.py 1  &
srun --nodes=1 --nodelist=sam-red --ntasks=1 --oversubscribe  python demo.py 2  &

wait
```

Now forces the first job to allocate only 2 CPUs. But the other are still queued even if i have quad-core CPU with hyperthreading.

Comment: Try adding `-n 1` to the `srun` arguments?

Comment: thanks for the help, not sure why but got it working after rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reboot my server for maintenance. 
Not sure what happened but now I can run the jobs in a parallel fashion using:

```
#!/bin/bash

srun --nodes=1 --nodelist=sam-red --ntasks=1 --oversubscribe  python demo.py 0  &
srun --nodes=1 --nodelist=sam-red --ntasks=1 --oversubscribe  python demo.py 1  &
srun --nodes=1 --nodelist=sam-red --ntasks=1 --oversubscribe  python demo.py 2  &

wait
```

The key to enforce parallel jobs on same node is the --nodes=1 argument. That alone is sufficient on my system.

for quick reference more examples are available here:

https://slurm.schedmd.com/cpu_management.html#Example6